# MySQL query to also calculate percentage

Tags: mysql

So im currently trying to create a MySQL query in which it gathers the percentage by calculating the total value column and making the username's value divide by it and x 100 in one single query, grouped by userid. any help?

having trouble with this:

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM `game".$cg."` GROUP BY `userid` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/K1H2Efg.png

Comment: my columns^ in database

Comment: `SELECT username, (SUM(value)/COUNT(value))*100 FROM game".$cg." GROUP BY userid ORDER BY id DESC`